# Inno Setup word completion doesn't work at all

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, word-completion

How does word completion work in Inno Setup?

If I press <kbd>Alt+Right</kbd> at the middle or at the end of any identifier or word in the code, nothing happens.

I can't find any extensions to install and I can't find answers on the internet to this topic...

(Inno Setup Compiler v. 6.2.0)

Answer (score 3):

Inno Setup compiler IDE can complete:

- Section names
- Standard section directives, parameters and flags
- Constants
- Preprocessor directives
- Pascal Script event function names

Nothing more. So indeed, it's not very useful in the Pascal Script code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, in fact I had specified the problem wrong because the problem was related to **Inno Setup Script Studio** IDE and not to the **Inno Setup** IDE.
All your solutions work perfectly. Thank you !